# Magento recalc order doesn't change total

Tags: magento, observers

I have an observer on 'sales_model_service_quote_submit_success' and I have modified dynamically a product price.
I tried recalculating the order but the totals never change.

Already have tried:

```
$ItemOfOrder->setCustomPrice(20);
$ItemOfOrder->setOriginalCustomPrice(20);
$ItemOfOrder->setPrice(20);
$ItemOfOrder->setBasePrice(20);
$ItemDoPedido->setOriginalPrice(20);

// Enable super mode on the product.
$ItemOfOrder->setIsSuperMode(true);
//$ItemDoPedido->calcRowTotal();
$ItemOfOrder->save();


$quote->setRowTotal(20);
$quote->setBaseRowTotal(21);
$quote->setRowTotalWithDiscount(22);
$quote->setBaseRowTotalInclTax(23);
$quote->collectTotals(24);
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_all');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nominal');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nonnominal');
$quote->collectTotals();
```

Comment: Did you try with $ItemOfOrder->setFinalPrice(20); ??

Comment: yes Pavan. No success :\

Comment: What happens when you add $quote->save() at the end?

Comment: Nothing, already have tried.
I debug all the $quote and the values are ok, but in the backend the orders totals dont change :\

Comment: I have a feeling that you might need to use sales_model_service_quote_submit_after

Answer (score 0):

And if you try to use the address data in de calculation?

```
$address = $quote->getAddress();
$address->collectTotals();
$quote->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal());
```